# Struggling setting up a pom.xml file. Keep getting Maven enforcer Rule 2 error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm currently working on an ImageJ plugin using Eclipse. I am struggling with setting up the pom.xml file, as whenever I run it I get an error saying: 
[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 12.0.1 is not in the allowed range [1.8.0-101,1.8.9999].

I attempted to fix this by tweaking the pom.xml file. This is the part I attempted to tweak:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-java</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>12.0.1</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>
              </rules>    
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    ...
</project>
```

However this kept giving me the same error. I have been looking all over the place to see what I could do to fix this, but I haven't had much success. I was wondering if anybody had a fix for the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

click your project > BuildPath > ConfigureBuild Path
Check your JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY VERSION. 
if you want to change version , click edit button
[image]
Check project Facets JRE Version.
[image]

Comment: Hi thank you so much for replying! So I attempted to change the build path, but changing it to any of the options does not work (I attempted to compile each time), and I do not have an option for Project Facets. I apologize for the late reply.